# Matrix/Grid FormType in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I need to create a matrix/grid type form widget in Symfony 2 but i'm not sure where to start, the docs for Forms don't seem to go into this level of complexity. I need to create something that's laid out like this:

```
---------------------------------
| Name   | HasRole1 | HasRole2  |
---------------------------------
| Jon    | Yes      | No        |
| Steve  | Yes      | Yes       |
| Dave   | No       | Yes       |
---------------------------------
```

Anyone have any pointers/advice?

Cheers,

Jon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this section of the docs ?http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

> Symfony gives you a wide variety of ways to customize how a form is rendered. In this guide, you'll learn how to customize every possible part of your form with as little effort as possible whether you use Twig or PHP as your templating engine....

Form Themes can help you :)